# SQL-Server Verify SHA2_512 hash procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, encryption, cryptography, sha512

Consider this method

```
declare @pswd nvarchar(max);
set @pswd = '2YKRCqHv';

Select 
    orig = a.Hash,
    hashA = 0x0200 + a.Salt + Hashbytes('SHA2_512', cast('2YKRCqHv' as varbinary(max)) + a.Salt),
    hashB = 0x0200 + a.Salt + Hashbytes('SHA2_512', cast(@pswd as varbinary(max)) + a.Salt)
from DB a

where 
a.Hash = 
0x0200 + a.Salt+ Hashbytes('SHA2_512', cast('2YKRCqHv' as varbinary(max)) + a.Salt)
or
a.Hash = 
0x0200 + a.Salt+ Hashbytes('SHA2_512', cast(@pswd as varbinary(max)) + a.Salt)
```

OUTPUT:

```
orig    0x0200BB316075603286E929221B9C04411AEC602A98B295CC05FCFFA809C2B553A100F4EBD4AA6FB3458E0B7C7E6D6B36FEA4908DF0AECA5142A26FA06B30F125253E15D585EE
hashA   0x0200BB316075603286E929221B9C04411AEC602A98B295CC05FCFFA809C2B553A100F4EBD4AA6FB3458E0B7C7E6D6B36FEA4908DF0AECA5142A26FA06B30F125253E15D585EE
hashB   0x0200BB316075C91147A2AEC396358C3F950C7E930B8DF0F9AC05628E00A74663502EE7BFCE68AA7BA3EC8303AE65107C72CAEF95111DD85CE45F210291B2800141CA37863A09
```

Why are A and B different? And how can I create a verify password procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in `hashA` you are `CAST`ing a `VARCHAR` to a `VARBINARY`, and in `hashB` you are `CAST`ing a `NVARCHAR` to a `VARBINARY`.

The first is non-Unicode, hence the difference.

Try:

```
declare @pswd nvarchar(max);
set @pswd = '2YKRCqHv';

Select 
    orig = a.Hash,
    hashA = 0x0200 + a.Salt + Hashbytes('SHA2_512', cast(N'2YKRCqHv' as varbinary(max)) + a.Salt),
    hashB = 0x0200 + a.Salt + Hashbytes('SHA2_512', cast(@pswd as varbinary(max)) + a.Salt)
from DB a

where 
a.Hash = 
0x0200 + a.Salt+ Hashbytes('SHA2_512', cast(N'2YKRCqHv' as varbinary(max)) + a.Salt)
or
a.Hash = 
0x0200 + a.Salt+ Hashbytes('SHA2_512', cast(@pswd as varbinary(max)) + a.Salt)
```

Note the addition of `N` in front of the password for `HashA`, which causes it to be Unicode, and then produces an identical result.

Alternatively, change the `@pswd` declaration to use a `VARCHAR`, which produces the same output as `orig`.

Comment: I was just about to answer the same when i saw your answer :). you can use this test script to improve your answer. `declare @pswd nvarchar(max);
set @pswd = '2YKRCqHv';
DECLARE @salt VARBINARY(MAX) =  0x0111
SELECT 1 WHERE 
0x0200 + @salt+ Hashbytes('SHA2_512', cast(N'2YKRCqHv' as varbinary(max)) +@salt) 
=
0x0200 + @salt+ Hashbytes('SHA2_512', cast(@pswd as varbinary(max)) + @salt)`

Comment: Aha ok. So if I change my declare to declare @pswd varchar(max); it works aswell :) Is this how I should verify a password? I looked at the PWDCOMPARE function, but can't get this to work. Guess that's not for SHA2_512?

Comment: @stibay `PWDCOMPARE` (and ultimately `PWDENCRYPT`) are considered to be out of date now, the `HASHBYTES` function you are using is actually significantly better.  See here for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822791.aspx

Comment: you wont be able to use a Salt with `PWDCOMPARE` either